# Problema no upload de arquivos em PHP

Tags: php, upload, zend, multiple-file-upload

Olá, estou com um problema no upload de arquivos do meu sistema. Ao colocar mais de 5 arquivos no campo "input multiple file" só são gravados 5 no banco de dados, ou seja, se eu colocar 18 arquivos somente vão ser gravados 5 arquivos.

O estranho, é que no arquivo php.ini o "max_file_uploads" está com o valor 20, o "post_max_size" e o "upload_max_filesize" estão com 64M.

Os arquivos são imagens e não chegam a 1mb.

Detalhes técnicos: PHP versão 5.5, Zend Framework 1.12.17

Trecho do controller que realiza o upload:

```
if (isset($_FILES ['fotos'])) {
    $fotos = $_FILES ['fotos'];
    //Inserção de multiplas imagens
    for($i = 0; $i < count($fotos); $i++) {
        //Inserção normal da imagem
        if (!empty($fotos ['name'][$i])) {
            $data_fotos = array();
            $data_fotos ['type'] = $fotos ['type'][$i];
            $data_fotos ['tmp_name'] = $fotos ['tmp_name'][$i];
            $ite->inserirFoto($codalb, $codusu, $data_fotos);
        }
    }
}
```

Dei um "print_r($_files["fotos"])" no controller, segue abaixo o valor do array:

```
[name] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01 - Copia (2).jpg
        [1] => 01 - Copia.jpg
        [2] => 01.jpg
        [3] => 02 - Copia (2).jpg
        [4] => 02 - Copia.jpg
        [5] => 02.jpg
        [6] => 03 - Copia (2).jpg
        [7] => 03 - Copia.jpg
        [8] => 03.jpg
        [9] => 05 - Copia (2).jpg
        [10] => 05 - Copia.jpg
        [11] => 05.jpg
        [12] => 06 - Copia (2).jpg
        [13] => 06 - Copia.jpg
        [14] => 06.jpg
        [15] => 07 - Copia (2).jpg
        [16] => 07 - Copia.jpg
        [17] => 07.jpg
    )

[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => image/jpeg
        [1] => image/jpeg
        [2] => image/jpeg
        [3] => image/jpeg
        [4] => image/jpeg
        [5] => image/jpeg
        [6] => image/jpeg
        [7] => image/jpeg
        [8] => image/jpeg
        [9] => image/jpeg
        [10] => image/jpeg
        [11] => image/jpeg
        [12] => image/jpeg
        [13] => image/jpeg
        [14] => image/jpeg
        [15] => image/jpeg
        [16] => image/jpeg
        [17] => image/jpeg
    )

[tmp_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => /tmp/phpfcCVZ1
        [1] => /tmp/phpXCYDdx
        [2] => /tmp/phpiLuvr2
        [3] => /tmp/phpFncCFx
        [4] => /tmp/php1KEYT2
        [5] => /tmp/phpQ8Fy8x
        [6] => /tmp/php3eRkn3
        [7] => /tmp/phpCGkqCy
        [8] => /tmp/php3fxNR3
        [9] => /tmp/phpZpvu7y
        [10] => /tmp/phpk6Dpn4
        [11] => /tmp/php5JhxDz
        [12] => /tmp/phpIGZTT4
        [13] => /tmp/php9gVwaA
        [14] => /tmp/phptxyor5
        [15] => /tmp/phpZmPtIA
        [16] => /tmp/php8LTHZ5
        [17] => /tmp/phpXna8gB
    )

[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] => 0
        [8] => 0
        [9] => 0
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 0
        [12] => 0
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => 0
        [17] => 0
    )

[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 186806
        [1] => 186806
        [2] => 186806
        [3] => 192111
        [4] => 192111
        [5] => 192111
        [6] => 277800
        [7] => 277800
        [8] => 277800
        [9] => 220789
        [10] => 220789
        [11] => 220789
        [12] => 265068
        [13] => 265068
        [14] => 265068
        [15] => 175393
        [16] => 175393
        [17] => 175393
    )
```

Como pode-se perceber ele vem com as 18 fotos.

Comment: Posta o trecho do código que faz o upload pra gente ver se tem algo estranho, não da nenhum erro? timeout? memória alocada?

Comment: verifica tambem o `post_max_size` e o `upload_max_filesize `  é o limite de cada arquivo e o limite total do post, digamos que esteja como 5mb e cada arquivo seu tenha 1mb, so vai enviar 5 arquivos. É mais ou menos nessa linha que funciona.

Comment: Tem como dar um `var_dump` em `$_FILES`, antes do `for`, para saber se estão chegando todos os arquivos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebe que o array `$_FILES["fotos"]` possui apenas 5 posições (*name*, *type*, *tmp_name*, *error*, *size*)? Por isso apenas 5 fotos são gravadas no banco.

Tente iterar sobre `$fotos["name"]`, por exemplo:

```
if (isset($_FILES ['fotos']))
{
    $fotos = $_FILES ['fotos'];

    // --------------------------vvvvvvvv
    for($i = 0; $i < count($fotos["name"]); $i++)
    {
        if (!empty($fotos ['name'][$i])) 
        {
            $data_fotos = array();
            $data_fotos ['type'] = $fotos ['type'][$i];
            $data_fotos ['tmp_name'] = $fotos ['tmp_name'][$i];
            $ite->inserirFoto($codalb, $codusu, $data_fotos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Era isto mesmo! Obrigado. Como faço para finalizar ou marcar a pergunta como resolvida? Sou novo por aqui hahaha

Comment: No lado esquerdo da resposta, logo abaixo do sistema de votos, há o botão com ícone de um "certo", só clicar nele.